# How do I create fixed number groups using regex?

Tags: regex, excel

In Excel, I have a column of dates all in different formats.

```
January 4 -9, 2019
January 22, 2019
January 28, 2019
January 31 - February 3, 2019 ***
January 29 - 31, 2019
October 28 – November 1, 2019 ***
```

I have this regex:

`([\w]+)[\s]+([\d]{1,2})[\s]?[-–]?[\s]?([\w]+)?([\d]+)?[\s]?([\d]{1,2})?,?[\s]?([\d]{4})`

which matches the above formats. The problem is for the dates with a second month (Jan/**Feb**, Oct/**Nov**) they are in group 3, which is the same group as the second day.

How can I have the second day to be in group 4 so everything is aligned?

What I want:

```
Group 1: Month 1
Group 2: Day 1
Group 3: Month 2 (if available)
Group 4: Day 2 (if available)
Group 6: Year
```

The reason I want to group is because I want to be able to split the columns to have `START DATE` and `END DATE`.

Using the first example:

```
Column B - START DATE: January 4, 2019
Column C - END DATE: January 9, 2019
```

If my regex can be simplified, that would be great. I also cannot figure out how to match the year start with 20XX. `([20][\d]{2})` doesn't seem to work.

https://regex101.com/r/5DXqdm/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be RegEx?  Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

In cell B2 and copied down is this formula for the Start Date:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(150),"-")&"-")-1))&", "&RIGHT(A2,4)))
```

And in cell C2 and copied down is this formula for the End Date:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),"",IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2&"-",CHAR(150),"-"))-1))),DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))&TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(150),"-"))+1,LEN(A2))))))
```

Format columns B and C as `MMMM d, yyyy`

Comment: Dafuq... how do you even figure out something like this? Are you able to explain it to me–not every detail but what each portion of the formula does?

Comment: @Julian, for Start Date, first part checks if it's already a valid date by itself, if so just uses that, otherwise it grabs everything up to the dash and combines with the 4-digit year at the end.  for End Date, it again checks if it's already a valid date by itself which means there is no End Date, and then it checks if everything after the dash is a valid date, and if not it grabs the Month from before the dash and then combines it with everything after the dash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if we can do that since there is an optional month in between, maybe you are going to have to add some additional capturing groups and then process those afterwards, other than than I can't think of a better way, or if possible, that'd likely be with look-arounds, which would make the expression pretty complex:

```
(\w+)\s+((\d{1,2})(?:\s+)?(?:[-–])?(?:\s+)?(\w+)?(\d+)?(?:\s+)?(\d{1,2})?),?(?:\s+)?(\d{4})
```

If I understand it correctly.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/h3MkyD/1)

Comment: NP. The UV is partly in compensation [for your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57207687), which unfortunately needed to be deleted - the OP is a help vampire, and they duplicated their last question (with a small change to ask for more detail).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - they were causing excessive work for community members anyway. Question authors can expect hefty downvotes if they copy+paste their questions.

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern causes the second day to always be in group 4:

```
([A-z]+) (\d{1,2})(?:.*?([A-z]+))?(?:.*?(\d{1,2}))?.*?(20\d{2})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sOjdVX/1)

The pattern, broken down, is as follows:

1. **Group 1** `([A-z]+)` matches any string of alpha characters. This matches the first month name. This is followed by a single space.
2. **Group 2** `(\d{1,2})` matches a one or two digit day number.
3. Non-matching optional group `(?:.*?([A-z]+))?` matches, if available, any characters followed by matching **Group 3**: a string of alpha characters `([A-z]+)`. This matches the optional second month.
4. Non-matching optional group `(?:.*?(\d{1,2}))?` matches, if available, any characters followed by matching **Group 4**: one or two digits `(\d{1,2})`. This matches the optional second day number.
5. Finally, `.*?(20\d{2})` matches any characters followed by **Group 5**: the characters `2`, `0`, then any two digits `(20\d{2})`.